# How to return a specific dateformat as DateTime datatype

Tags: c#

I'm making a query with entity framework and I need to compare 2 datatime. One from field and the other from a select. The problem is that I need to convert the user input to datetime but in the format I want and with the datatype I need. I need to return a value like this:

```
DateTime date = Convert.ToDataTime("2012-02-30");
```

But the date variable has the value of `2012/02/30` and I need with this format `2012-02-30` and the datatype **must be DateTime**

Comment: `DateTime`s have no format associated with them.

Comment: Date values don't have a format - you choose the format (or it's chosen for you via defaults) when you _display_ the date/time.  How are you displaying (or where are you seeing) the dates in that format?

Comment: Take a look at [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) EDIT: And for outputting in a specific format, the [ToString(format)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) overload.

Comment: entity framework should do the work for you.

Comment: @DanielA.White and what happends if the value format in the databas field want to compare the is 2009-06-31 and the input is 2009/06/31?

Comment: @user2195741 are the columns datetime types?

Comment: @DanielA.White sorry for responding so late. Yeah they are DateTime

Comment: @user2195741 entity framework/ado.net will do it automatically.

Comment: @DanielA.White Just now i edited my code and yeah, i realized that entity do it automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned before, DateTime values have no format associated with them.  All DateTimes are handled as Dates, regardless of the string format that they were generated from.

If your issue is generating a DateTime object from a string, look into things like

```
Convert.ToDateTime
```

or

```
DateTime.TryParse
```

if your issue is comparing two date times, there are built in comparison operators that function just as well on DateTime that they do on anything else.

```
UserDate.Equals(FieldDate)
UserDate > FieldDate
UserDate < FieldDate
```

etc etc and so on.

and finally, if your issue is string formatting and you cannot control exactly what the user entered, then you need to ask that question specifically, because we will need to know more about what the user CAN enter, to tell you what you might be able to do with it.

**Added Edit**

It looks like the last one is your issue anyway...

try using a simple character replacement.

```
string newString = DateString.Replace("/", "-");
```

this will ONLY work with that single, specific, formatting change...but it will do what you seem to want to do.

Answer (score 0):

In C# a `DateTime` object does not have a format associated with it until you convert it to a string.  It can then be formatted in whatever way you want.

Similarly, when you load the value from text, it is converted to a `DateTime`.  You can then run the comparisons on this object.

```
DateTime date1 = Convert.ToDataTime("2012-02-30");
DateTime date2 = Convert.ToDataTime("2012/02/30");

if (date1 == date2) Console.WriteLine("They match!");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have asked the wrong question I believe, due to a misunderstanding as to how DateTime works. It doesn't store the value as a string. Your strings are in reality just a representation of a Datetime.

What you actually need to do is look at the DateTime.ToString() overrides.

**LINK** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx

When you output your DateTime, use something like

```
date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

and you will get the desired format.

In terms of the underlying theory though, the datetime itself is not stored as a string. You only need to worry about the way you display it.